# El Capitan - Losing internet connection every 20/30 minutes

Tags: network, wifi, internet

MBP Early 2015 keep losing internet connection! Still connected to the router but no data in or out, can't even access router settings.

If I toggle wifi on and off it will be good for 20/30 minutes and then same cycle. What should I do, what is the problem?

I know the same exact question is out there but nothing is working!

I have tried:

- Remove [airport/network configs](http://innov8tiv.com/fix-os-x-el-capitan-wifi-problems-wifi-not-working-slow-internet-in-os-x-el-capitan/)
- `sudo ifconfig awdl0 down`
- 5gHz band
- Removed network
- Replaced modem
- Cleared DNS cache
- Removed proxies in network settings
- Disabled "wake for wi-fi network access

Don't know what else to do... Haven't done any PRAM or SMC resets.

Comment: Does this happen on all networks you connect to or just one?

Comment: @samh I don't know at the moment. I will test this in couple hours on a public network.

Comment: @samh Happens on all networks. I just tried my bootcamp and no issues at all and way faster speed than I get on osx!

Comment: @Devrim Did you ever find a solution? Same thing is happening on my 2012 MacBook Air running El Capitan. Other people have reported the same problem here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/209881/38302

Comment: @JimRhoades yes Jim I have. This lead to another issue which you can follow here + solution is also there... 

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263232/dns-cannot-connect-to-the-internet

Answer (score -1):

If you create a new user account in macOS and that solves the problem, then you have a configuration issue or an app or daemon misbehaving.

If that does not solve the problem, based on the steps you've taken already, check to make sure your router/access point has its firmware up to date.

If it's up to date, you might try resetting it to its defaults.

Comment: OP stated their using El Capitan, not macOS Sierra.

Comment: I don't think my suggestions would change? If you think it should be OS X El Capitan but macOS Sierra feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: I created a new user and nothing changed. Issue persists after sierra update as well. But bootcamp is smooth :|